# Sprite is not positioned correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working on a (test)game to learn SpriteKit trying to make my own card game.

I am creating a side bar that should be moved out by SKAction, the animation it self works. I have created a black bar in the correct sizes for iPhone and iPad, called "backmenu~iphone.png" (50p) and "backmenu~ipad.png" (100p).

The problem i have is that i am able to position the black bar correctly on iPhone but not on iPad, it is positioned to low, and i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong. I do set the anchorPoints and place the sprites on the same coordinates. The sprites are the correct sizes.

The code:

```
SKSpriteNode *menuOnMainScreen = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"backmenu"];
        menuOnMainScreen.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.1);
        menuOnMainScreen.position = CGPointMake(_menuPositionOutsideOfScreen, 0);
        menuOnMainScreen.name = @"backmenu";
        menuOnMainScreen.zPosition = 1000;
        [self addChild:menuOnMainScreen];
        
        SKAction *moveMenuIntoScreen = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(0, 0) duration:0.3];
        [menuOnMainScreen runAction:moveMenuIntoScreen];

        SKSpriteNode *arrowLeft =  [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"arrow_left"];
        arrowLeft.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        arrowLeft.position = CGPointMake(_setWidthPositionInSideMenuCoordinate, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) * 0.95);
        [menuOnMainScreen addChild:arrowLeft];
```

The following parameters are used:

> _menuPositionOutsideOfScreen = -50 on iPhone
>
> _menuPositionOutsideOfScreen = -100 on iPad

When i run the code it looks as follows, iPhone on the left and iPad on the right:

[image: iPhone] [image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that your `anchorPoint`'s y is 0.1

Shouldn't it be :

```
menuOnMainScreen.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you make **anchorpoints** 0.5, 0.5 and positions them **self.size.height/2** in y-direction, and **_menuPositionOutsideOfScreen** on x-direction?

Its a bit hard to test it without more code, but try it out